# Error when i add another struct in this movie class , Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Error while adding another struct in this file**

```
var body: some View {
   VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Image(movie.thumbnail)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

**New struct**

```
struct Cast: View {

var body: some View {

    HStack {
        VStack {

            Text(cast.name)
                HStack {
                 NavigationLink(destination: detailsCast(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selection = 1;
                    })
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Could you share your full struct body?